# Why couldn't my images be loaded successfully in React?

Tags: reactjs

I was trying to add several images on the page, but after rendering, it showed the pictures were broken. Could someone help me figure out what was the problem?

There are my original codes:

```
import React from 'react';
import Product from "./Product/index";
import Data from "../../../data/data.json";

const ProductList = () => {
    const renderedList = Data.goods.map(product => {
        return <Product product={product} key={product.name} />
    }
);   

    return (
        <div>{renderedList}</div>
    );
}

export default ProductList;
```

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Thumb from "../../../Thumb/index";

const Product = props => {
        return (
            <div className="shelf-item">
                <div className="shelf-stopper">Free shipping</div>
                <Thumb 
                    classes="shelf-item__thumb"
                    src={props.product}
                />
                <p className="shelf-item__title">product</p>
                <div className="shelf-item__price">
                    productInstallment  
                </div>
                <div className="shelf-item__buy-btn">Add to cart</div>
            </div>
        );
    }

export default Product;
```

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
import React from 'react';

const Thumb = (props) => {
    return (
        <div className={props.classes}>
            <img 
            src={`/Users/xlz/Desktop/codingProject/react/new- 
                  shopping-cart/src/static/products/${props.src.pictures}`} 
            alt={props.src.name} />
        </div>
    )
}

export default Thumb;
```

This is the hierarchy of my folders:

```
new-shopping-cart
  src
      components
        Thumb
          index.js

      static
        products
          xxxxxxxxxxxx.jpg
          xxxxxxxxxxxx.jpg
          xxxxxxxxxxxx.jpg
```

I am sure that the paths of pictures are correct. But on the page, there were broken pictures with alternate texts for the images.

Comment: If the page displays broken pictures, then the URLs are broken. Look into the rendered HTML and see what is inside the `src` attribute. I would expect something like `http:///Users/xlz...`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I checked the `src` attribute and found when my mouse was hovering on the `src`, it showed `http://local:3000/Users/xlz/Desktop........`. Is there a problem with this path?

Comment: `local:3000` is the root of your server, not the root of your file system. Your URL should probably be just something like `/static/products/...` so that the result is ` http://local:3000/static/products`. Make sure that your images are copied to your distribution folder.

Comment: I changed my URL to `../../static/products/${props.src.pictures}` and the result was `http://localhost:3000/static/products/xxxxxxxxx.jpg`, but it still didn't work. I have added the hierarchy of my folders in my original question, I thought there seems to be no problem.

Comment: change pictures destination. means you need to transfer your pictures to your project, inside your server directory

Comment: I am sorry I didn't catch your point. What does `server directory` mean?